# Javascript function differences, is there any?

Tags: javascript, function

When I run a function in js it seems to work fine but will this be fine?

function myfunction(){
}

VS

var myfunction = function(){
}

Because both are called the same so does it make no difference?
Sorry new to js so i'm just making sure it's good to learn this style. (The first function is what i'd prefer to use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already asked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/6303162), 
One of the basic difference comes from declaration, for instance :-

```
foo();
var foo = function(){
console.log('hi');
}
```

would lead to undefined, since it is called before it's declared, on the other hand,

```
foo();
function foo(){
console.log('hi');
}
would console 'hi' with no problem, for further insight check the above link.
```

Comment: Thanks, so when I make it a variable it's a local function and without the variable it's a global function?

Comment: variables are always local unless you specify them as global.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [W3Schools Function guide](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp)

> You can use a function **declaration** or a function **expression**.

Both are the same in general. Thought there are certain things to consider:

- In a function expression the function is only defined when that line in code is reached
- In a function decleration the function is defined as soon as the code is run, so it can be called before it is written in your code (due to [hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp))

The first example you wrote is a function **Declaration**

The second example you wrote is a function **Expression**

The only difference between the two is how you will invoke them in your code after you defined them.

If you are wondering which is better, it all comes down to which you are more comfortable with and think the syntax for is more readable, also try not to mix up the two to keep conventions in your code.